# Is it possible to write single query for following scenario?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to write single query for following scenario?

Scenario -

Table -

```
column name      -          id           date                isPaid
values           -           1        1/1/2011                1
                             2        1/2/2011                1
                             3        1/3/2011                0
                             4        1/4/2011                0
                             5        1/5/2011                0
```

I want a result set which contains (all ispaid = 1) and (only 1 row of ispaid = 0 whose date is smaller).

Result set:

```
column name         -       id           date                isPaid
values              -        1        1/1/2011                1
                             2        1/2/2011                1
                             3        1/3/2011                0
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`<sup>docs</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

```
SELECT
    [id],
    [date],
    [isPaid]
FROM
    [tablename]
WHERE 
    [ispaid] = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1
    [id],
    [date],
    [isPaid]
FROM
    [tablename]
WHERE 
    [ispaid] = 0
ORDER BY 
    [date] ASC
```

Comment: @ypercube, why the `ALL` addition ? There can be no duplicates.. (*I have reverted to my original answer for now, but if you can give me some arguments we can put it back on*)

Comment: I searched and it seems the `UNION ALL` is better performance than `UNION`.. so thanks to @ypercube for the improvement

Comment: If the optimizer can figure out that there are no duplicates, then it's not needed. But it doesn't hurt, it's like forcing the optimizer to not do any sorting (and comparing) during `UNION`.

Comment: @ypercube, χεχε :) ντόπιο πράμα... (*excuse us for the local language comments..*)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need in SQL Server 2005 and higher.

```
select
   [id],
   [date],
   isPaid
from (  
     select 
         [id],
         [date],
         isPaid,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ispaid order by date) as row
     from table_name t ) a
where ispaid = 1
    or row = 1
order by [date]
```

Comment: Or simply: `ispaid = 1 or row = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date will be provided to the query by user, for which data is to be retrieved

```
select t.* 
from table t,
(select Top 1 id, date, ispaid
from table
where ispaid = 0 and date<?) np
where (t.ispaid=1 and t.date = ? ) OR (t.id = np.id)
```